# Create a Play Framework project as a part of the big project

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have a Scala project ("solution") which contains a few projects in it. I also want to add one more project in this main "solution" -- a Play Framework application. Now it looks like this:

```
main_project
 - project1
 - project2
 - project3
```

I want it to be:

```
main_project
 - project1
 - project2
 - project3
 - play_project
    - app
    - public
    - project
    - logs
```

When I try to do that, it creates the directories right in the main project:

```
main_project
 - project1
 - project2
 - project3
 - play_project
 - app
 - public
 - project
 - logs
```

And it also renames the `main_project` to be `play_project`.

How do I do what I want to?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some reading up on multi module projects in sbt, someone might be able to give you a solution that works but unless you understand how it works you are going to have serious problems with it in the future.

Checkout the sbt docs for the version of play that you use, http://www.scala-sbt.org, also I'd recommend you to read the SBT in Action MEAP from Manning. There is some docs on multimodule builds in the play documentation but those focuses on having play as the main project and not on defining a super-project like you are describing.